# stuck in if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

### I tried this but its not working

i want to be execute both the if statements `if (addTxt.textLength == 0)` And `if (headingTxt.textLength == 0)` and then,
if both the condition will true then else block to be execute but its not working
help me to get this issue resolve

```
    // If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    let headingTxt = document.getElementById("headingTxt");
    if (addTxt.textLength == 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box!")

    }
    if (headingTxt.textLength == 0) {
        alert("Please Give some Heading To Your Note!")
    }
    else {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        }
        else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push({text: addTxt.value, heading: headingTxt.value, date : new Date()});
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        // console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    }
})
```

Comment: Unless you are using SVG, I think you might be looking for `.length`, not `.textLength`. And it would be an option on the string returned when you get an elements content/value, not the element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the function by `return` when one of your conditions meets, and you should use `.value.length` instead of `.textLength` for finding the length of input field value.

```
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  let headingTxt = document.getElementById("headingTxt");
  if (addTxt.value.length === 0) {
    alert("Please write something in text box!");
    return; //stop further logic in this function
  }
  if (headingTxt.value.length === 0) {
    alert("Please Give some Heading To Your Note!");
    return; //stop further logic in this function
  }

  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notesObj.push({
    text: addTxt.value,
    heading: headingTxt.value,
    date: new Date(),
  });
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addTxt.value = "";
  // console.log(notesObj);
  showNotes();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much but i tried this tooo,
its not working 
take a look on my solution

Comment: Ahhh I forgot that we should use `.value.length` instead. Good catch! Glad that you're able to solve it :D @MohammedVaraliya

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

```
// If user adds a note, add it to the localStorage
let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    let headingTxt = document.getElementById("headingTxt");
    if (addTxt.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box!")

    }
    else if (headingTxt.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Please Give some Heading To Your Note!")
    }
    else {
        let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
        if (notes == null) {
            notesObj = [];
        }
        else {
            notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
        }
        notesObj.push({text: addTxt.value, heading: headingTxt.value, date : new Date()});
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
        addTxt.value = "";
        // console.log(notesObj);
        showNotes();
    }
})
```

Comment: Your solution may face [this little code visibility problem](https://janalmazora.medium.com/how-to-prevent-using-if-else-statements-in-your-code-7e05e43afde). I'd suggest that you should use early returns.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. You just group them in one condition:

```
if (addTxt.textLength == 0 && headingTxt.textLength == 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `headingTxt.length` not `headingTxt.textLength`

Comment: no its still not working coz the id="headingTxt" is from input tag

Comment: If you want you can use `headingTxt.value.length`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
if (addTxt.value.length === 0 && headingTxt.value.length === 0) {
//do this
}
else {
    if (addTxt.value.length === 0) {
        alert("Please write something in text box!");
        return; //stop further logic in this function
    }
    if (headingTxt.value.length === 0) {
        alert("Please Give some Heading To Your Note!");
        return; //stop further logic in this function
    }
}
```